# chromeでログインした状態からログインする前に戻す

Tags: google-chrome

chromeであるサイト開発をしていてログインをしているのですが、ログアウトするボタンがなく、ログイン前に戻すことができません。

chromeでログイン情報を削除する方法があるときいたのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: ログイン情報をどこに保存しているかが重要です。開発しているサイトの仕様によって変わります。一般的にはCookieにセッションIDを持たせることが多いですが、同様の仕様になっていますか？それとも独自の機構でログインのセッションを維持させていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

設定画面を開いたら「自動入力」 > 「パスワード」 > 「保存したパスワード」で一覧から該当のエントリを削除してみてください。

もしくは「シークレットウィンドウ」の機能を使えば、保存されたログイン情報を無視して新たにログインすることもできるはずです。

Comment: 質問のログイン情報とは自動入力ではなくてセッション情報（CookieやWebStorageなど）ではないでしょうか？もちろんその場合シークレットウインドウやゲストブラウジングは有用です